# Data not saving in database in Django

Tags: html, django, database, sqlite, django-forms

I am trying to save data into the database from the website. My web page is taking the data (image from my system) but in the database, it's not showing up. If I add manually then it's creating a new user entry and storing it.
Here are my files:

models.py

```
class Details(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=122)
username = models.CharField(max_length=122)
email = models.EmailField(max_length=122)
password = models.CharField(max_length=20)
def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class Image_Data(models.Model):
    img_User = models.ForeignKey(
        Details, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    img_password = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
    return str(self.img_password)
```

forms.py

```
class ImageForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Image_Data
    fields = ('img_password',)
    labels = {
        'img_password': 'Add your image ',
    }
    widgets = {
        'img_password': forms.FileInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Upload from device'})
    }
```

views.py

```
def register_new_b(request):
saved = False
if request.method == "POST":
    # take whatever is posted to the Details Form
    form = ImageForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        messages.success(request, 'Your message has been sent!')
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/register_new_b?saved=True')
else:
    form = ImageForm()
    if 'saved' in request.GET:  # sends saved var in GET request
        saved = True

return render(request, 'register2.html', {'form': form, 'saved': saved})
```

Here is what I get in database upon saving the image [image]

Answer (score 2):

In the line:

```
form = ImageForm(request.POST)
```

you need to add request.FILES:

```
form = ImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
```

*Edit

An working example inside my own code:
in `views.py`

```
def change_profile_pic(request):
    context = dict()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProfilePictureForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.store(request.user.id)
            form = ProfilePictureForm()
            context['success_message'] = 'Picture changed'
            request.user.employee.refresh_from_db()
        else:
            context['error_message'] = 'Unable to change picture'
    else:
        form = ProfilePictureForm()
    context['form'] = form

    return render(request, 'template.html', context)
```

in `forms.py`

```
class ProfilePictureForm(forms.Form):
    image = forms.ImageField(required=True)

    def store(self, user_id):
        user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
        user.employee.profile_picture = self.cleaned_data['image']
        user.employee.save()
```

in `models.py`

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pictures', max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
```

But I have also experimented with ModelForm, and this also saves the file correcly

Comment: i tried this. But still not displaying the image name in the database

Comment: Looking agian (after my edit), I see that you are missing `upload_to` in your ImageField, not just the `request.FILES` in the form initalization

Comment: I tried adding a similar function as store() in your code. It throws an error : ImageForm' object has no attribute 'store'

Comment: As per my example, I created this function by my self and is not a standard form function